# SSLPeerUnverifiedException with non-standard SSL Port only

Tags: android, ssl

My Android client (Samsung G4, Android 4.4.2) is attempting to negotiate a connection on port 8443, producing the this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

However, if I negotiate a connection over the standard 443 port all is well.  The problem seems limited to Android.  I found this [link asserting the same problem](http://digitaljive.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/bug-android-error-111-neterr_tunnel_connection_failed/).  But most of my other searches have just yielded SSL issues on old versions of Android.

Is there a problem with overzealous host-name checking?  I'm used to problems with certificates, but not with a certificate working on the same domain, but failing when the port is changed.